# Are these two definitions identical or different

Tags: recursion, f#

Looking at the following definitions:

```
let rec extractOdds list = ​
  match list with ​
  | [] -> []​
  | x::xs -> ​
      if x%2=0 then extractOdds xs else x::extractOdds xs​
```

and

```
let rec extractOdds list = ​
  match list with ​
  | [] -> []​
  | x::xs -> ​
      let rest = extractOdds xs​
      if x%2=0 then rest else x::rest​
```

I was wondering if the two are identical. Since, the first definition uses the recursive call straight away. Whereas, the second one creates a let binding to `extractOdds xs` and uses it in the `if` expression.

Please guide me if the two are implemented identically or differently.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very small difference between the two that has no effect in practice:

- The first version evaluates the condition `x%2=0` before evaluating `extractOdds xs`
- The second version calls `extractOdds xs` before evaluating the condition `x%2=0`

The order will be preserved in the compiled code (which might be a bit longer for the first version), so the two versions are slightly different, but this is not observable in any way - the two calls are free of side-effects and the call to `extractOdds xs` happens regardless of whether `x%2=0` is `true` or `false`.

This might be more obvious if you rewrite the first version using a `let` binding too:

```
let rec extractOdds list = ​
  match list with ​
  | [] -> []​
  | x::xs -> ​
      if x%2=0 then 
        let rest = extractOdds xs 
        rest 
      else 
        let rest = extractOdds xs​
        x::rest
```

Now you can clearly see that the order of the condition and let binding is the only difference from:

```
let rec extractOdds list = ​
  match list with ​
  | [] -> []​
  | x::xs -> ​
      let rest = extractOdds xs​
      if x%2=0 then 
        rest 
      else 
        x::rest
```

**EDIT:** A tail-recursive version can be written using the "accumulator" parameter. This way, you collect the elements in the wrong order, so you need to reverse the resulting list before returning it:

```
let rec extractOdds acc list = ​
  match list with ​
  | [] -> List.rev acc
  | x::xs -> ​
      extractOdds (if x%2=0 then acc else x::acc) xs​
```

Comment: Is the statement `let rest = extractOdds xs` in the second version a call. I thought its is just like binding a name "rest" and the actual call happens in the `if` or the `else` blocks.

Comment: @S.Singh In F#, the bindings are evaluated eagerly - which means that the `let rest = extractOdds xs` statement actually evaluates the call `extractOdds xs`. (Haskell is an example of a language where this would be evaluated lazily - only when the value is actually needed.)

Comment: Does this mean that the result would computed only when the call stack is unwound. Is there some way of converting this to tail recursion.

Comment: See edit for a tail-recursive version. The result is computed in the same way as it would be in other eager languages - like in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the tail recursive version. But I am still slightly confused about the version 2 of the function. In case `let rest = extractOdds xs` is a call, then what happens when control hits `rest` in the `if` or `x::rest` in the `else` blocks.